# jQuery on() doesn't work with dynamically add events

Tags: jquery

I use PHP curl to send data to a listening port and output the data on the screen and it works well.
This is the data I sent:

```
$arr = array("message" => "<u>".$abc."</u> at <u>".$currentDate."</u> || <a href=#>Call</a> || <a href=#>SMS</a> || <u class='caller'>N/A</u>");
$msgString = json_encode($arr);
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8123/message');
curl_setopt($ch,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,
            "POST");
curl_setopt($ch,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            $msgString);                                                          
curl_setopt($ch,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,
            true);                                                              
curl_setopt($ch,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-Type:application/json',
                  'Content-Length:' . strlen($msgString)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

This is working perfectly. Then I use Chrome to watch the elements. All elements are OK.
[image]
Next I use jQuery to bind them click function but I can't trigger them.

```
//alert("123");
$('.caller').on("click", function(){
  console.log("11");
});
```

PS: The code is in a external js file and I include jquery library correctly in the main file. I use alert to test and it works.
I think the problem is the js code. I don't know why I can't trigger the click event. Could someone tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: You are using on like a normal click, you should read the api for the event delegation parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on("click", '.caller', function(){
  console.log("11");
});
```

Better option will be pass selector of parent element of .caller that you don't update dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".caller",function() {
console.log("11")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you located the function that attaches the handler:?

```
$('.caller').on("click", function(){
     console.log("11");
});
```

If this is called in `$(document).ready` or equivalent then it will only attach to `.caller` elements **that have already been created** - it will not attach to elements created in the future. To do this you would need to call that function again each time new `.caller` elements are added to the DOM.

Comment: Or better, use delegation